# How to track any click made on the page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I try to find event that is called when I do left click over page.
It should be event that brings data about click and element under click was made. I can be text, image - any HTML layout.

Is it possible to do in Chrome Events Extensions? Also tell me if exists dev tool for development Chrome Extensions. Thanks.

Comment: Content script contents only custom JS, written on native JS, but I seems I need event of chrome instead. Then what is event in content script?

Comment: Maybe I can use this method in `content_script`? `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   
});`?

Comment: No, content_script is a content script, browserAction is a toolbar icon popup.

Comment: Well, how to call event click in content.js?

Answer (score 2):

You can detect where a user clicks on the page easily, by implementing a `click` handler on the `body` element of the page. The event that is fired has a `target` property, which identifies the element the user has clicked on.

Below is a simple implementation of this. It is followed by an extension specific idea for running on any page, where you inject the code via a content script, and use messaging to send the data to the background page, via the content script (you can't send direct to the background page).

```js
var clickTable = document.getElementsByClassName('click_table')[0];

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    var tag = document.createElement('td');
    tag.innerHTML = e.target.tagName;

    var id = document.createElement('td');
    id.innerHTML = e.target.id;

    var className = document.createElement('td');
    className.innerHTML = e.target.className;

    var parent = document.createElement('td');

    parent.innerHTML = e.target.parentElement ? e.target.parentElement.id ? e.target.parentElement.id + ' / ' : '' + e.target.parentElement.className : '';

    row.appendChild(tag);
    row.appendChild(id);
    row.appendChild(className);
    row.appendChild(parent);

    clickTable.appendChild(row);   
});
```

```css
.red_box {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

.blue_box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    background: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.click_table {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.click_table tr td, .click_table tr th {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red_box">
    <div class="blue_box">
    </div>
</div>

<table class="click_table" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Tag</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Parent Id/Class</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For the Chrome Extension, you could do something like:

In the `click` handler, after getting your data, dispatch an event:

```
 var event = document.createEvent('Event');
 event.data = row; // whatever data you want
 event.initEvent('click_from_page');
 document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

**Content script:**

The content script can listen for the event, and forward that data to the background page.

```
document.addEventListener("click_from_page", function(e) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(e.data);
});
```

**Background page:**

The background page can listen for the event send from the content script.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    // received the data from content script
});
```